# How bad is a 2 year publication gap in your CV for an early career researcher?

Tags: cv, publications

I am currently at the end of my second year as a postdoc in the life sciences field, with my contract lasting a total of three years. I did my masters and PhD at other institutions and then started at my current lab. I finished my PhD in 2018 and worked for a year as a temporary lecturer at my home university before starting the postdoc. As I am in a very experimental heavy project, I still have not published anything from the postdoc, with my last publication from the PhD having come out in 2019. I believe we will publish something from my current project probably next year in a relatively high impact journal. I guess my main concern is to what extent this 2 year publication gap (2020 and 2021) might affect my CV when applying for jobs later.

Comment: "I believe we will publish something from my current project probably next year in a relatively high impact journal." Is this your one and only one publication from the project? As a postdoc you should have some side-projects and collaborations that lead to additional publications if your main project doesn't lead to several publications. The publication gap doesn't matter as much if you still average 1+ publications per year.

Comment: Publication expectations vary greatly by field and location, and what type of jobs you're looking for.  Have you tried asking senior faculty in your area about this?

Comment: @Roland I think we will have more than one publications from this project, the more immediate ones that come to mind would be two. I have a few collaborations, but those (also quite experimental) will probably lead to publications a bit later down the line. Thx for the input!

Comment: What would you do with the answer? Since you cannot change this.

Comment: @AzorAhai-him-I just wanted to have a feel of how people perceive this issue and check if this could be a deal breaker

Answer (score 2):

If you had been idle for that time it might matter, but if you are doing significant research, then you can't schedule results. Schedules work for *known* things, but not for the *unknown*.

But, your past is your past. If you work to produce good results they will (probably) come eventually.

The CV may show a blank section, but if asked about it, you certainly have some reasonable things to say. Focus on the quality of the research and results, not the time it took to get there.